# How to query all of the movies that a cast belongs to using its slug in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models: `MovieCast` and `Movie`. The `MovieCast` model includes an `actor_name` field and the `Movie` model includes a `cast` field which has a many-many relationship with `MovieCast` model.
In the templates, I'm displaying the cast objects that are related to a movie. An example would be something like this:

```
Schindler's List
    cast: Liam Neeson, Ben Kingsley
```

Each of those actors are the `actor_name` fields of a cast object, which, again, is related to the movie (i.e. "Schindler's list"). What I am trying to do is have a link which contains the actor's name as slug (I also have an `actor_slug` field in the `MovieCast` model) and when that url is clicked, we get all of the movies that an actor is included in.

What I tried to do is as follows:

- Include a link which will route to something like
  `/movies/cast/{{ actor_slug }}`
- Include a url in `urls.py` which will direct a link such as above to a view
- Write a class based view, say `MovieCastView`, and modify its `get_queryset` method like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # the actor_slug will come from the link that I previously mentioned
    self.actor_slug = self.kwargs['actor_slug']
```

What I can't figure out is how do I get all of the movies that a cast has using that `actor_slug`.
In other words, how do I use the `actor_slug` field which will be inside the `MovieCast` model and use that field to get a cast object so that I can get the movies which have relationship with such cast object?

Comment: `movie_cast_object.movie_set.all()`

Comment: @VishalSingh Sorry, I don't understand. How do I use the actor_slug to get the cast object so that I can do cast_object.movie_set.all()? Also where is the movie_set attribute coming from? Can you please clarify?

Comment: `MovieCast.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('actor_slug'))`. Although if you use `DetailView` this would be put as self.object by the view itself.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Do you want to use a `ListView`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the super queryset and filter using the kwargs:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    # the actor_slug will come from the link that I previously mentioned
    actor_slug = self.kwargs['actor_slug']
    queryset = queryset.filter(cast__slug=actor_slug) # Assuming the slug field is named slug
    return queryset
```

Note: you may actually want to ensure the MovieCast object exists in which case below implementation would be better:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    actor = get_object_or_404(MovieCast, slug=self.kwargs['actor_slug'])
    queryset = queryset.filter(cast=actor)
    return queryset
```